# MYSQL concat after Left Join is not showing values

Tags: mysql, left-join, concatenation

I have a list A:

```
Item | Company 
1    | aa
2    | bb
```

List B:

```
Item | Info
2    |  blablabla
```

I have following query:

```
SELECT a.item, concat(A.company, ' - ', B.info) 
From A LEFT JOIN B on A.item = B.item
```

This is what I get:

```
1    None
2    bb - blalal
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
1    aa - 
2    bb - blalal
```

Comment: Please post (add to your question by using [edit]) the result you would like to get.

Answer (score 2):

`concat()` returns `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`  One simple solution is `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT a.item, concat(A.company, ' - ', coalesce(B.info, '')) 
From A LEFT JOIN
     B
     on A.item = B.item;
```

You seem to want the separator.  If you didn't, an alternative is:

```
SELECT a.item, concat_ws(' - ', A.company, B.info)
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. So we have a concat_ws that add separator between all arguments and skip the NULL value, but we don't have a regular version of concat that skip NULL ?

Comment: @viviwill . . . Yes, you seem to understand the two functions.  I think the NULL behavior for `concat()` is defined by ANSI.  In addition, there is no easy work-around using `coalesce()` with `concat_ws()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of IFNULL

```
SELECT A.Item, CONCAT(A.Company, ' - ', IFNULL(B.Info,'')) 
FROM A  
LEFT JOIN B ON A.Item=B.Item;
```

Comment: coalesce() is the sql standard and should be used instead of ifnull()